# Find a solution to inequality

Tags: inequality, logarithms

$$\log_{\tfrac{1}{5}}\log_{11}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}+x}{3}\right)<\log_5\log_{\tfrac{1}{11}}\left(\sqrt{x^2+3}-x\right)$$
With an explanation, if you can. Thanks.

Comment: $(\sqrt{x^2+3}+x)/3=1/(\sqrt{x^2+3}-x)$

Comment: Please show that you have put some effort into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$\log_{\tfrac1{11}}\Bigl(\sqrt{x^2+3}-x\Bigr)=\log_{11}\frac 1{\sqrt{x^2+3}-x}=\log_{11}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}+x}3.$$